# Notificaciones PUSH (duda)

Tags: python, django

He estado viendo un curso y quería implementar notificaciones PUSH sobre mi proyecto, pero en el curso que imparte la persona, tiene una estructura completamente diferente a la mía y la verdad estoy recién aprendiendo a usarla, de una manera más estructurada.

El objetivo es recibir una notificación PUSH al momento de agregar un nuevo producto, o sea, que realice un evento al clickear el botón de send. Mi clase de agregar producto en la view es la siguiente

```
class ProductoNew(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,SinPrivilegios,generic.CreateView):
permission_required = "producto.add_producto"
model = Producto
template_name = "productos/producto_form.html"
context_object_name = 'obj'
form_class = ProductoForm
success_url = reverse_lazy("productos:producto_list")
login_url = 'generales:login'
success_message = "Producto creado correctamente"
```

Me surge una gran duda y el no saber de cómo poner el siguiente código en esa clase

```
dispositivos = FCMDevice.objects.filter(active=True)
dispositivos.send_message(
    title="Pelicula agregada"
    body="Se ha agregado: " ´formulario.cleaned_data['nombre'],
    icon="/static/core/img/logo.png"
```

)

Estoy trabajando con el paquete FCMDevice para capturar los tokens de los usuarios y mandarles las notificaciones, pero intenté poner el mismo código debajo seguido de la clase con un

```
if formulario.save()
```

Para poder realizar la acción de mandar la notificación, pero por alguna razón no completa el proceso. Acaso no se puede hacer en una clase?, debo hacer otra?

Estoy trabajando con Django y Python.

Comment: hola te recomiendo que integres la API de INDIGITALL, funciona Excelente para integrarlo el tu App o Sistema, con Api podrá configurar las notificaciones a tu Gusto,programadas con imágenes,fechas, localización entre muchas funciones mas aqui te dejo el link del Servicio para que te Documentes: https://docs.indigitall.com/es/apis/